# Several image snapshots in a JLabel component

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I want to create a print preview for a variable-size set of images in Java. My first approach (in dev mode) was to create snapshots of the images in different JLabels (just as a quick developer solution).

But for the production solution I need to create a more efficient and elegant way to display the images for the user of this standalone software. So I was thinking in showing him maybe 7-8 snapshots of the images to be printed on each JLabel.

Is there another way to do this? (Speaking of Java GUI components)

Comment: *"a more efficient and elegant way"* You are over-thinking this.  Use as many labels as are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store these `Images` in some sort of `List<Image>`, such as `ArrayList<Image>`. Please read the [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) tutorial, which contains related examples. There are other examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm).

Comment: In the scope of my question: Is it correct to print 7 or 8 images in a JLabel? Or there is a more elegant way do achieve this?

Comment: @josej30 `to print 7 or 8 images in a JLabel` are you meaning place to the one JLabel

Comment: yeah, I mean place **all of them** in just **one** JLabel. Is that ok?

Comment: no idea (for better advice) what did you tried, but JLabel is best of JComponent for diplaying Image in Swing GUI, please look at Icon / ImageIcon too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html